# await returns pending promise

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

in this sample rez contains pending Promise. I need to get it resolved with other code paused till it's get resolved:

```
 function getCoordinates() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
    });
}

async function getAddress() {
    await getCoordinates();
}
const  rez =  getAddress();
alert('wait for rez');
```

I know I can do something like `getAddress().then(function () {  alert('wait for rez')} );` but is there a way to continue not inside of `then` scope?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the async operation as well:

```
(async function(){
  function getCoordinates() {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
      });
  }

  async function getAddress() {
      await getCoordinates();
  }
   const rez = await getAddress();
   alert('wait for rez');
})()
```

Comment: That only works if `await getAddress()` is inside an `async` function.

Comment: You are correct, you can switch it to use `promise` syntax

Comment: And can I do `alert('wait for rez');` not inside ` getAddress().then(...` but make it on next line of code?

Comment: @Drunkwolf Only if it is inside an `async` function. Otherwise you are out of luck.

Comment: @Ivar if code goes up to `$(document).ready`...   how can I make it `async` too?

Comment: @Drunkwolf Try `$(document).ready(async function () {...` Then you can use `await getAddress()` to wait for it.

Comment: @Ivar for some reason it did not work with `$(document).ready` but worked with `$(window).load`

Comment: I've updated my code, basically you need global `async` one trick would be to wrap the code with iffe

Answer (score 0):

As was commented functions wich calls promise needs to be `async` otherwise it returns pending promise.

```
$(window).load(async function () {
    var rez = await getCoordinates();
    alert(rez.coords.latitude);});

function getCoordinates() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
});};
```